# Hyperparameter Optimization for One vs All Classification

Tags: model-selection, multi-class, hyperparameter

For a multi-class classification problem, using One-vs-All classification in which a separate binary classifier (regardless of whether the classifiers are linear or non-linear) is trained for each of N classes is it best to optimize a single set of hyperparameters to use for each of the N classifiers, or is it possible to get better prediction accuracy by optimizing a separate set of hyperparameters for each binary classifier?

For example, if I have a classification problem with 3 classes and I am using a gradient boosting machine for each classifier, should I use the multinomial log-loss to optimize a single set of hyperparameters (e.g. number of trees, number of splits per tree, etc.) to be used in each classifier? Or would it be better to use binomial log-loss to fit hyperparameters for each model independently of the others and then evaluate the expected generalization error for the OvA classifier as a whole using the multinomial log loss?